# JSON array - extract the lat lng

Tags: php, json

I have a function that is trying to get the coordinates from a json array. It has me stumped so I was hoping someone would see my error.

```
function getCoords($location){
        $loc = urlencode($location);
        $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$loc&sensor=false";
        //echo $url;
        //echo file_get_contents($geo_url);
        $json_result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

      $geo_result =  $json_result->results[0];
        $aCsv = $geo_result->geometry->location;


        //see if the it is locating the real address or just apox location, or in most cases a bad address
        if($aCsv->location[0] == 200) {
        return array('lat'=>(float)$aCsv[2], 'lng'=>(float)$aCsv[3], 'prec'=>(int)$aCsv[1]);
         }

        var_dump($aCsv);
    }
```

The var dump is below I need to extract just the lat and lng in this format 42.3584308,-71.0597732, 21.3069444, -157.8583333

```
object(stdClass)#12 (2) { ["lat"]=> float(42.3584308) ["lng"]=> float(-71.0597732) } object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["lat"]=> float(21.3069444) ["lng"]=> float(-157.8583333) }
```

I think this part is where I am running into my issue

```
if($aCsv->location[0] == 200) {
            return array('lat'=>(float)$aCsv[2], 'lng'=>(float)$aCsv[3], 'prec'=>(int)$aCsv[1]);
```

TIA steve

Guys is there a way to access the JSON data outside of the function? I would like to  take the actual address that is being parsed and show that in the result ing calculation.

Sometimes google maps does not use the exact location for instance if I type in KLAX - Los Angeles airport if uses a address in Germany but if I put LAX it uses teh LA airport so it would be nice to see the parsed address as well.

I can echo the address thats being parsed within the function but when I try to use it outside the function it is NULL.
Thanks Again for your assistance.
Steve

Comment: Change the line if($aCSV->location[0]==200) { to if(isset($aCsv)) {
Also, you'd need to change the return to $aCsv['lat'] instead of $aCsv[2], same for longitude

Comment: you can directly get associative array using json_decode(), just pass TRUE as second parameter in json_decode() function

Comment: Jamie the isset did the trick, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trees and woods? ***You already have it*** !!

```
function getCoords($location){
    $loc = urlencode($location);
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$loc&sensor=false";
    $json_result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

    $geo_result =  $json_result->results[0];
    $aCsv = $geo_result->geometry->location;

    echo 'lat : '.$aCsv->lat.'<br>';
    echo 'lng : '.$aCsv->lng.'<br>';
}

getCoords('alabama');
```

outputs

> lat : 32.3182314
>   lng : -86.902298

Comment: Thank you guys It finally works. been pulling my hair (whats left ) out for 2 days!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data   = json_decode($ResponseData); 

if('OK' === $data->status){
    $latitude       = $data->results['0']->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitude      = $data->results['0']->geometry->location->lng;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to work with a assoziative array so you can use this:

```
$json_result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true)
```

(http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php)

Then the values are available with:

```
$json_result["lng"]
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$loc.'&sensor=true');              

$output = json_decode($geocode);

if($output->results)
{


   foreach($output as $data)
   {

       $lat      = $data[0]->geometry->location->lat;
       $long     = $data[0]->geometry->location->lng;
       $location = $data[0]->formatted_address;
   }
}
```